# Compare Two Databases Perl

Tags: perl, comparison, compare, teradata

I want to compare the data structures/data types/lengths of two different **TERADATA** databases residing on **two different servers**, using Perl

Is it possible to do this?

**Added detail**
 I'm trying to compare these two databases (one PROD) and (one DEV) environment databases and compare PROD to DEV and record the differences, I can't export to a flat file, then import into another place because the size of the data being copied is upwards of 500gb.

I'm first trying to compare PROD to DEV server databases, then with the differences in the schemas/datatypes/length, import into DEV from PROD.

Comment: export the database from one and import it on the other (as a different name). then you can write php to compare from there

Comment: Yes, which database you are using? probably you will have to find any builtin way that DBMS provide to compare and that implement that builtin mechanism in your perl script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this in pure Perl, per your question, might be difficult, but it could be done using [`DBI`](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.616/DBI.pm).  Assuming MySQL on `DB.YOURDOMAIN.COM` and `DB2.YOUROTHERDOMAIN.COM`:

```
my $db1 = DBI->connect(
     'DBI:mysql:database=DATABASE1;host=DB.YOURDOMAIN.COM;port=3306',
     'username', 'password',
     );
my $db2 = DBI->connect(
     'DBI:mysql:database=DATABASE1;host=DB2.YOUROTHERDOMAIN.COM;port=3306',
     'username', 'password',
     );
```

This will get you your two connections.  From there, you would just execute the queries to get the job done:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("show tables");
while (my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) {
   my $table_name = $row->{'Tables_in_DATABASE1'};
   ## Process this particular table.
}
```

For the individual tables you cal use `describe`:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("DESCRIBE table1");
while (my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) {
    my $type = $row->{'Type'}; ## 'int(12)' for example.
    ## Process from there.
}
```

Comment: Ok... I am not familiar with Teradata, but according to this (http://forums.teradata.com/forum/database/table-metadata-inspection) you probably have some equivalent commands.  And then there is the Teradata driver for DBI:  http://search.cpan.org/~darnold/DBD-Teradata-1.52/lib/DBD/Teradata.pm

Answer (score 1):

A few different methods come to mind.  If both databases are accessible from a single machine, then you can build the data into Perl datastructures, then use Test::More::is_deeply() to check differences.

If the databases aren't both accessible, then build the data in Perl as above, and then use Data::Dumper to print the structure to a file. Make sure to use the Sortkeys option, as well as use the same Indent/Purity/etc. options on both runs. Finally, copy the two output files to the same place and run 'diff' on them.

Comment: See Added Info above and provide example script (if possible). Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried querying the metadata on the schemas, tables, and columns (and putting each into a relevant data structure)--for example:

```
{
   schema1=>
       [{table11=>[[column111,datatype111],[column112,datatype112],...],
        table12=>[[column121,datatype121],...
       ]
    ,schema2=>[{table21=>[[column211,datatype211],[column212,datatype212,...],
        etc...]
}
```

and then traverse each data structure, comparing each schema, table, and column?  Unless you give us some more specifics, I don't think you'll get much more of a useful answer.

Comment: In that case, yes, you'll want to query the metadata.  Exactly how you go about doing that depends on your RDBMS.

Comment: Its TERADATA, added that above.

Comment: In that case, you'll need to look up how to query the metadata in a Teradata database.